# C# Metro app - adding controls to specific row and column in grid

Tags: c#, xaml, grid, controls

I want to create some control object (`Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle` to be specific) and add it programmatically to `Grid` control, which is created in designer. I've searched a lot and I didn't find what I need - many answers said about `SetRow` and `SetColumn` methods. The problem is that, apparently, those functions just don't exist in new XAML (**edit:** `Grid` I'm talking about is in namespace `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls`, not in `System.Windows.Controls`).. I've tried adding control as a children to grid:

`grid.Children.Add(Rectangle);`

The control is added in the center of a first row/first column cell in `Grid`, which is pretty logical, but how to add next `Rectangle` into first row and i.e. second column?

Here's some actual code:

```cs
public void Draw(ref Grid grid)
{
    Color rectColor = new Color()
    {
        R = 90,
        G = 90,
        B = 90,
        A = 255
    };

    Brush rectBrush = new SolidColorBrush()
    {
        Color = rectColor
    };

    Square = new Rectangle()
    {
        Fill = rectBrush,
        Height = 40,
        Width = 40
    };

    grid.Children.Add(Square);
}
```

Above method is of course part of bigger program, but when I finally manage to fit one control into one cell described by row and cell number, I guess it'll be simple to make it for the rest (I need 15x15 board).

Last thing - as I've noticed, all these `Grids` and other layout-controls don't seem to work as tables, so my approach may be completely wrong. When controls is added directly in designer, it just automatically fits into right row and column. So, should I somehow only arrange children controls in `Grid`?

Sorry, if this question is trivial, I just have no idea, how to do that, I'm trying like two days, so I'll be very grateful for any advices.

Comment: Have you tried grid.SetRow and grid.SetColumn?

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned it in post, there's just no such methods. I'll update it a little, because the difference is in namespace, I've forgotten to write about this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use two **static** methods to do this. `SetRow` and `SetColumn`. e.g.

`System.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.SetRow(your row num, your control)`

According to this they should be there:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.setrow.aspx

Comment: They are, but it would work only for Windows Desktop, in case of applications for Windows Store it seems to be totally different - `Grid` is not equal to `Grid`, I just love it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use grid.SetColumn(UIElement, int) and Grid.SetRow(UIElement, int)

Comment: I think there's no such methods in new C#, I wrote about this (the difference is in namespace, `Grid` that you're talking about is in namespace `System.Windows.Controls`, the one I ask about is in `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls`). It would be really nice to have them, but unfortunately it's not that simple :(

Comment: You would be correct. You are trying to use two different frameworks, with no commonality. You'd have to implement your own Rectangle UIElement to use Grid methods.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to read about this. It just seems so weird, that we can add controls to a given row and column from the designer, however there's no simple way to do that from code, considering that XAML controls are pretty much editable from C#. Thank you for your responds.